Inheritance chain and SUPER keyword
For the following code from Docs (I replaced events with console logs):
import "hardhat/console.sol";
contract Owned {
    address payable owner;
    constructor() { owner = payable(msg.sender); }
}

contract Emittable is Owned {
    event Emitted();

    function emitEvent() virtual public {
        console.log("EMITTABLE");
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            emit Emitted();
        }
    }
}

contract Base1 is Emittable {
    event Base1Emitted();
    function emitEvent() public virtual override {
        console.log("BASE1");
        super.emitEvent();
    }
}


contract Base2 is Emittable {
    event Base2Emitted();
    function emitEvent() public virtual override {
        console.log("BASE2");
        super.emitEvent();
    }
}

contract Final is Base1, Base2 {
    event FinalEmitted();
    function emitEvent() public override(Base1, Base2) {
        console.log("FINAL");
        super.emitEvent();
    }
}

It says, "If Final calls a function of super, it does not simply call this function on one of its base contracts. Rather, it calls this function on the next base contract in the final inheritance graph, so it will call Base1.emitEvent() (note that the final inheritance sequence is – starting with the most derived contract: Final, Base2, Base1, Emittable, Owned)."
Where I fail to understand how Base1 is the next base in inheritance chain ? Shouldn't it be Base2.emitEvent() ?
Because, i just tested it in remix, the logs are (FINAL, BASE2, BASE1, EMITTABLE).

The text by itself is contradictory https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#inheritance. It should be a mistake in the documentation. Try contacting the solidity team so it could be fixed.

Thanks for the clarification, @Ismael.

This is due to how Solidity resolves the inheritance order. The inheritance chain is linearized so that all base classes are processed in a way that avoids diamond inheritance problems (i.e., calling the same function twice from different paths). Even though Base1 is listed first in the inheritance declaration, C3 linearization dictates that Base2 should be called first in the derived class (Final) because Base2 comes later in the linearization order, i.e.,:
Final → Base2 → Base1 → Emittable → Owned

So, when you call super.emitEvent() in the Final contract:

It first calls Base2.emitEvent().

Base2 then calls super.emitEvent(), which goes to Base1.emitEvent() because of the linearized order.

Base1 then calls super.emitEvent(), which reaches Emittable.emitEvent().


That’s why, the logs are showing in this order:
FINAL → BASE2 → BASE1 → EMITTABLE


That wasn't even my question. I know how to serialize. I already wrote the Inheritance chain there.

Yes, but I think I've addressed your question regarding why BASE2 is getting logged before BASE1, in the line where it says C3 linearization dictates that Base2 should be called first in the derived class (i.e., Final) because Base2 comes later in the linearization order.

But, Nowhere in my question did I ask "why BASE2 is getting logged before BASE1".

Can you share the url of the doc that you’re referencing in your question?
